# Parent child loop in python

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have a list of strings like below.

`headers = ['Header_1|C11', 'Header_1|C12', 'Header_2|C21', 'Header_2|C22', 'Header_2|C23']`

I want to create a loop which will give result like below.

`result_string = "Header_1 C11 C12  Header_2 C21 C22 C23"`

The below script prints the "child" values but not the headers. How can I extend it to get the above `result_string`?

```
childstr=''

for i in headers:
    child=i.split('|')[1]
    childstr += child + '   '

print childstr
```

Comment: Could you clarify if the original "String" is a string or list of strings?

Comment: It's coma separated values. Anyway if you want you can make it to list of strings

Answer (score 0):

This is one approach using a simple iteration and `dict.setdefault`. You can also use `collections.defaultdict` inistead of `setdefault`

**Ex:**

```
headers = ['Header_1|C11', 'Header_1|C12', 'Header_2|C21', 'Header_2|C22', 'Header_2|C23']
r = {}     #using defaultdict --> r = collections.defaultdict(list)

for h in headers:
    key, value = h.split("|")
    r.setdefault(key, []).append(value)

result = " ".join("{} {}".format(k, " ".join(v)) for k, v in r.items())
print(result)
```

**Output:**

```
Header_1 C11 C12 Header_2 C21 C22 C23
```

Answer (score 0):

Plese check this.

```
Stringlst = ['Header_1|C11', 'Header_1|C12', 'Header_2|C21', 'Header_2|C22', 'Header_2|C23']


result_dict = {}
for item in Stringlst :
    key, value = item.split("|")
    if result_dict.get(key):
        result_dict[key].append(value)
    else:
        result_dict[key] = [value]

out_put_str = ""
for key, value in result_dict.items():
    out_put_str += key+" " + " ".join(value)+ " "
print(out_put_str)
```

Answer (score 0):

Could you please try below:

```
prev_header = ''
childstr=''
for i in headers:
    header = i.split('|')[0]
    child=i.split('|')[1]
    if prev_header != header:
        childstr += header + '   '
        childstr += child + '   '
    else:
        childstr += child + '   '
    prev_header = header
        #childstr += child + '   '
print (childstr)
```